# How to sort FK filter in symfony's admin generator using Doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I've got a symfony admin generated module for my Poem class.  My poem table has a foreign_key constraint to my MasterIndex table (user_id).  When using the Symfony admin generator, in list mode, it displays a drop-down filter for my user_id.  I can change the data that is being displayed by modifying the __toString() method in my MasterIndex class to display the user name instead of the Id.

How can I sort the data that is being displayed in the filter drop-down?

I found [this](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowtoSortAdminGeneratorListByForeignTableName) link which proposes a solution, but the `peer_method` that it uses only seems to work with Propel.

I'm using Doctrine 1.2 with my Symfony 1.4 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find available options for the `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice.class.php#L35-48)

```
* model:        The model class (required)
* add_empty:    Whether to add a first empty value or not (false by default)
                If the option is not a Boolean, the value will be used as the text value
* method:       The method to use to display object values (__toString by default)
* key_method:   The method to use to display the object keys (getPrimaryKey by default)
* order_by:     An array composed of two fields:
                  * The column to order by the results (must be in the PhpName format)
                  * asc or desc
* query:        A query to use when retrieving objects
* multiple:     true if the select tag must allow multiple selections
* table_method: A method to return either a query, collection or single object
```

You can use the `order_by` option like this: `...->setOption('order_by', array('some_field', 'asc'))`.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to order by multiple fields you can write a custom query and add multiple order by to it and then use the `query` or `table_method` option instead of `order_by`.

E.g. (you should write the query into a table class instead):

```
$query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('UserTable')->createQuery('u')->orderBy('u.last_name asc, u.first_name asc');
$this->getWidget('user_id')->setOption('query', $query);
// if you add some where condition to the query
// don't forget to set it to the validator as well
$this->getValidator('user_id')->setOption('query', $query);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - where does that code need to go?  Where/how do I tell the admin generator in generator.yml which method to call and from which class?

Comment: It should go into a generated filter form class's configure method. E.g. `  public function configure() { $this->getWidget('user_id')->setOption('order_by', array('some_field', 'asc')) }`

Comment: Works great. Tx.  Is there a way to sort with multiple fields (ie: order by last_name asc, first_name asc, dateOfBirth desc)? I've tried looking through the sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice object, but it seems it only takes a single argument for the order_by parameter.  And if I specify multiple cascading ->setOption('order_by', ...) it will only use the final cascade in the sql statement.